# Regex for OADC SMS number

Tags: regex

i want to create a regex for OADC SMS in html balis:

Condition:

```
-It must not contain spaces
-It must not start with the character 0
-It must not contain accented characters
-It must not contain punctuation like * $ <,> ?!
-It must not contain any Greek characters
-It does not have to be entirely digital.
```

i tried to make one `^[[^0][A-Za-z0-9\s]]+` but it doesnt work.

any help ?

Thank you

Comment: Try `^(?!0)[A-Za-z0-9]+$` `It does not have to be entirely digital` does that mean that there has to be at least another character than a digit or is only digits also ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make sure that the character class does not start with a zero, you could use a negative lookahead instead `(?!0)` of `[^0]`

Using `[^0]` will match any char except a zero and it requires a match making the pattern having to match at least 2 chars.

You can omit `\s` from the character class and use single `[` `]` to denote a character class.

```
^(?!0|\d+$)[A-Za-z0-9]+$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?!0|\d+$)` Assert not starting with 0
- `[A-Za-z0-9]+` Match 1+ times any of the listed in the character class
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZxtYWe/1)

---

Or without using a lookahead you can match the character class using 1-9 instead of 0-9 for the first character:

```
^(?!\d+)[A-Za-z1-9][A-Za-z0-9]*$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?!\d+$)` Assert not only digits
- `[A-Za-z1-9]` Match any of the listed, but only a digit 1-9
- `[A-Za-z0-9]*` Match 0+ times any of the listed
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TRLnT6/1)

Comment: but the problème this regex accepte string of numbers like 78582 
(It does not have to be entirely digital.) thank you

Comment: @BrahimDjarallah I have updated the answer to not match only digits.